# Is "yum groupinstall" compatible with Red Hat Network?

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel5, package-management

On CentOS 5, I run `yum groupinstall "Development Libraries"` to install the commonly used development libraries. Can I use the same command on a RHEL5 server with RHN? Is the "Development Libraries" group defined on such a server? Will it break the RHN updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this should still work.  I have never installed anything by group like that on our servers, but if you do `yum grouplist`, it shows up so the install should work the same.  There may be different packages in the group (which you can determine by `yum groupinfo "Development Libraries"`), but the command works the same.

You are still pulling the packages from the RHEL repos, so doing group installs won't break RHN compatibility.  If you add non-standard repos, you may have difficulties, but pulling everything from RHN by groups is fine.